# how do I put cards beside each other in html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put these cards beside each other in a row but whatever I try to write in the display nothing seems to work.  one card is showing perfectly and in it's position so can anyone tell me how can I fix this issue.

```html
<div class="row">
            {% for doctor in recdoc %}
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                        <div class="single_jobs white-bg d-flex justify-content-between" style="width: 50px;">
                            <div class="single_candidates text-center" style="height: 350px;">

                                <div class="thumb">
                                    <img class="img-circle " src="{% static 'static_file/img/candiateds/2.png' %}"
                                         alt="">
                                </div>
                                <a href=""><h4>{{ doctor.6 }} {{ doctor.7 }}</h4></a>
                                <p> {{ doctor.9 }}</p>
                                <div class="best-rating">
                                    <div class="text-warning">

                                        {% if doctor.16 == 1 %}
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        {% elif doctor.16 == 2 %}
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        {% elif doctor.16 == 3 %}
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        {% elif doctor.16 == 4 %}
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        {% elif doctor.16 == 5 %}
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                        {% endif %}


                                    </div>
                                    <div class="best-rating">
                                        <h5>تقييم الدكتور</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                        </div>

                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

and here is a screenshot to the output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have `col-lg-10 col-md-10` for each card. Bootstrap has 12 columns. Each of those take up 10 of those columns. Change the 10 to 6, 4 or 3 and test it.

Comment: Remove the `.col` classes. Then instead of `.row` on the container,  use `.flex-row`.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap grid system each row contains 12 columns, so you have to set columns properly, or you can use `float:left;`
give `float:left;` to your card div.

Have a look at [cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) or [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):